# Javascript packed decoder, translation needed

Tags: javascript, python

I've found a snippet to decode/unpack a JavaScript packed code (Dean Edwards), now I want to use this snippet in my code (python) to decode a string. I'm a newbie in python and I don't really know much about JavaScript, can someone translate this for me?

The snippet can be found at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SaXad/)

The decoding part is as follows:

```js
function Decode() {
eval("var value=String" + input.value.slice(4));
output.value = value;
}
```

(input and output = textarea)

the slice and eval part is unclear.
I've tried to use substring but the result is not the same as in jsfiddles' output.

Answer (score 0):

You cant simply translate this into Python. Since the actual "decoding" is done by running the obfuscated code. So `slice` or `substring` is not the point. The point is:

**You need a javascript engine to do this.**

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer, maybe there's a python module which lets me execute javascript directly.

Comment: Yes. There are some choices. If you just want js, then pyv8 is the way to go. If you need DOM, then probably a headless webkit binding like phantompy will do.